# Using two underscores before variable ( __fetchedResultsController )?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this double underscore in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566594/what-is-this-double-underscore-in-cocoa)

I've seen a variety of Core Data code examples that use two underscores instead of one.  I am aware of the advantages of iVars and using _variableName...But is there a particular reason/advantage for using two instead of one?  such as __fetchedResultsController = ...

Comment: It means the variable is twice as private as with one underscore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no real reasons to use a double underscore.

I will say that I'm not a fan of them though, because some things in Objective-C use them, such as:

`__block` or `__unsafe_unretained`

When I see the `__`, I tend to think of it firstly as a decorator that Apple has defined. If anything, it adds an extra second of thought to it, whereas the single underscore is universally understood to be a class' iVar.

I'd suggest just using `_`.

From [the accepted answer to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/566715/420001) "What is this double underscore in Cocoa?":

> C compilers (and by extension Objective-C) reserve names beginning with two underscores and a capital letter for use by the compiler vendor, giving them a reserved namespace to use for global variables and functions used to implement standard libraries, or to introduce new non-standard keywords like `__block`.

[A summary of the ANSI C standard](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/ansi-c-summary.html) says:

> External identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved for library usage.