# What is the meaning of leading and trailing underscores in Linux kernel identifiers?

Tags: c, linux, coding-style, kernel

I keep running across little conventions like `__KERNEL__`.

Are the `__` in this case a naming convention used by kernel developers or is it a syntax specific reason for naming a macro this way?

There are many examples of this throughout the code.

For example some functions and variables begin with an `_` or even `__`.

Is there a specific reason for this?

It seems pretty widely used and I just need some clarification as to whether these things have a syntactical purpose or is it simply a naming convention.

Furthermore I see lots of user declared types such as uid_t. Again I assume this is a naming convention telling the reader that it is a user-defined type?

Comment: The `_t` tells you it is a type made by `typedef`.

Comment: Cheers for the response. Sorry, to clear up an ambiguity, when I say user-defined types I indeed mean those defined by typedef.

Comment: Sure. As for the underscores, my guess is to prevent a macro being used where it was not intended when it has an ambiguous name with a function or class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325815/what-does-double-underscore-mean-in-variable-name-in-c-language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several cases:

- In public facing headers, i.e. anything that libc will be taking over and putting under `/usr/include/linux`, the standards specify which symbols should be defined and any other symbols specific to the system shall start with underscore and capital letter or two underscores. That's the reason for `__KERNEL__` in particular, because it is used in headers that are included both in kernel and in libc and some declarations are different.
- In internal code, the convention usually is that symbol `__something` is workhorse for `something` excluding some management, often locking. That is a reason for things like `__d_lookup` . Similar convention for system calls is that `sys_something` is the system call entry point that handles context switch to and from kernel and calls `do_something` to do the actual work.
- The `_t` suffix is standard library convention for typedefs. E.g. `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `foff_t` and such. Kernel code follows this convention for it's internal types too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With all of the coding style documentation about the kernel, I'm surprised that I don't find a lot of documentation on the naming conventions in the kernel. Did you just pick up these things by doing kernel hacking?

Comment: @KarateSnowMachine: Well, the first and last point come from C standard. The middle point, mostly yes. I didn't do any serious kernel hacking, but I had an assignment in kernel back at school, so I had to read quite a bit of the code (especially to double-check the locking).

Answer (score 0):

There are several __functions, as i.e. __alloc_pages_nodemask() that seems also be exported. Also, __functions are static, static inline, or globals too.  Btw, observing __alloc_pages_nodemask() is called only from mm code, and in no other place, such functions may be meant "internal" of some kernel framekwork.