# Do preprocessor macro definitions need to be in CAPS in a header file?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, header-files, definition

In the code I'm writing, I have been told to define a variable in a header file in the following way:

```
#define CLR_BLACK 0x0000
```

and since this is the only example I've been given, I was wondering whether all variables defined in a header file with the #define command need to be in caps. For example, would the following be valid?

```
#define videoBuffer (u16*)0x6000000
```

Comment: These are not variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** You can use any combination of alphanumeric characters and underscores. Don't start with a number.

However a variable name like `videoBuffer` would be difficult to distinguish from regular variables (without syntax coloring). That's why most people either use all caps for preprocessor macros or start them with a lower case `k`, like this: `kMyPreprocessorMacro`

EDIT: Those are not "global variables" by the way (as you tagged). They're preprocessor macros. Basically an automatic find and replace mechanism that is run at compile time.

Comment: so that videoBuffer example there would in fact be vaild?

Comment: Yes it would be valid. However a variable name like that would be difficult to distinguish from regular variables (without syntax coloring). That's why most people either use all caps for preprocessor macros or start them with a lower case `k` like that: `kMyPreprocessorMacro`.

Comment: right, thanks for that additional clarification on preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`#define` is a pre-processor macro. It replaces every occurrence of the first string after it with whatever comes after the string. The first string does not need to be in caps.

Answer (score 0):

No, but it's a common and useful convention so if you're reading the code you can see what's a macro and what isn't.  See [C++ #ifndef for include files, why is all caps used for the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799478/c-ifndef-for-include-files-why-is-all-caps-used-for-the-header-file)