# How to use a global variable for "configurations" in multiple tests in Googletest framework

Tags: c++, googletest, emscripten

I am using Google test framework for C++. Each file includes a config.hpp which defined a global configuration variable. I would like to define my config in a variable, not a compile-time const or `constexpr`. How can I define the dependencies to have the same variable in different files that are linked together? Do I have to use a singleton? Can I avoid that? Is there a better recommended way to use multiple test files xUnit style?

My config file:  `config.hpp`:

```
#pragma once
struct {
    const float tolerance = 0.001;
    // ...
} CONFIG_VAR;
```

Each test *.cpp source file is like:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "core/config.hpp"
TEST(a, b) { ... }
```

My main file:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I compile and link using:

```
em++  -I $GTEST_ROOT/googletest/include main_all_tests.cpp test_*.cpp
```

PS. My problem is multiple definition of the variable CONFIG_VAR.

My solution is based on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443970/separate-test-cases-across-multiple-files-in-google-test).

Comment: I can't spot a _global variable_ in your code sample?

Comment: It's `CONFIG_VAR` defined in `core/config.hpp`

Comment: what is your real problem? Is that multiple definition of CONFIG_VAR? Then it is duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370413/multiple-defined-symbols-c-error

Answer (score 6):

Everything you need is [right here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md) at the Google Test's official repository on GitHub.

Anyway, to sharing something in the same file test you do it like that:

```
class YourTestCase : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:

    virtual void SetUp()
    {
        globalObject = new YourObject();
    }

    virtual void TearDown() {
        delete globalObject;
        globalObject = nullptr;
    }

    Object * globalObject = nullptr;

};
```

so, in your test cases:

```
TEST_F(YourTestCase, TestOne) {

    ASSERT_EQ("your value here", globalObject->getValue());

}

TEST_F(YourTestCase, TestTwo) {

    ASSERT_EQ("your value here", globalObject->getValue());

}

TEST_F(YourTestCase, TestThree) {

    ASSERT_EQ("your value here", globalObject->getValue());

}
```

**Note.:** Pay attention to the function's name. It is **TEST_F** not **TEST**.

On the other hand, if what you want to do it is at the test program level ― sharing something among files, you will need to set up an environment object. Something like this:

```
Environment * AddGlobalTestEnvironment(Environment * env);
```

I have never worked with that before, so I can not tell you so much about it, but there is more information at that link I shared above. Usually, global variables make the code harder to read and may cause problems. You'd be better off avoiding them.