# Error message "undefined reference for `CPU_ZERO'"

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I included:

```
#include <sched.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

Then in my code I have written (brief mention):

```
cpu_set_t set; 

CPU_ZERO(&set); 
CPU_SET(proc_num, &set); 
if (sched_setaffinity(gettid(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &set))
{
    perror("sched_setaffinity");
    return NULL;
}
```

But when I compile I find

```
undefined reference to 'CPU_ZERO'

undefined reference to 'CPU_SET'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to place

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

at least **before**

```
#include <sched.h>
```

as the define steers what the file included shall provide.

More on this on [the related man-page here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/CPU_SET.3.html).

---

**Update**:

To make sure everything is set as needed, place the `#define` at the very beginning of your source files, that is before all `#include`s.

Alternatively you can pass the `#define` on GCC's command line by specifying the option

```
-D_GNU_SOURCE
```

Comment: basically it worked after defining before all the library functions.

Comment: @LinconFive: Not really. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10687353/694576 or this one, being even more explicit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7297011/694576