# Where to finding the precise meaning of a double underscore variable

Tags: c, reserved-words

This question pertains to C. There have been many questions already on the topic of double underscore variables, e.g.,
[What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)
[Why do people use __(double underscore) so much in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224397/why-do-people-use-double-underscore-so-much-in-c)
[Meaning of double underscore in the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687053/meaning-of-double-underscore-in-the-beginning)

As I understand thus far, `__myvar` is reserved for use by the compiler. However, I am unsure where to find the precise meaning for such variables, and how to use them.

For example, I am studying this block of code:

```
#define fatalError(...) { char str[1000]; sprintf(str, __VA_ARGS__); printf( "%s (%s in %s, line %d)\n", str, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

For instance, it's not clear what `__VA_ARGS__` refers to. Since it's reserved by the compiler, and I'm using gcc, should I be searching for `__VA_ARGS__` in gcc documentation?

Comment: You could always Google it, same as for any variable (including ones that don't have double underscores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule for determining the meaning of an identifier (not necessarily a variable name) whose name starts with two underscores (or with an underscore and an uppercase letter; those are also reserved to the implementation).

Some such identifiers are defined by the C standard.  Examples are `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__STDC__`, `__STDC_VERSION__` (all predefined macros) and `__func__` (not a macro but an implicitly declared identifier in each function).

You can find a draft of the C standard at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf.  Note that the PDF encodes double underscores in an odd way so they're displayed properly, so a search for `__STDC__` will likely fail.  You can search for `_STDC_` instead.

Any such identifiers not mentioned in the standard may be defined by the implementation (either the compiler or the runtime library).  Consult your implementation's documentation.  Be aware that some such identifiers might not be documented if the implementation uses them only for its own internal purposes.

As for `__VA_ARGS__`, that's defined by the C standard, in section 6.10.3.1.  It's used in variadic macros (macros that can accept a variable number of arguments). It's also documented in the gcc manual.

Comment: Thanks, Keith, for the thorough explanation. Even though the gcc manual is specifically on gcc, a large part applies to other popular compilers, too, right? I'm reading the part on the preprocessor and it seems the behavior is similar for the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: @DDC: The section of the gcc manual that discusses `__VA_ARGS__` clearly says that it's an ISO C standard feature. gcc has another mechanism for variadic macros with a different syntax; it predates C99. Some compilers (clang, for example) are deliberately compatible with gcc; MSVS is not.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html). It allows the function to take variable ammout of arguments. You can read more about functions with variable arguments [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm).

Comment: Thanks Seprum - I'm assuming this is gcc-specific, i.e. if I tried compiling this on a Microsoft compiler, it wouldn't work, right?