# return double from C function, using macro expansion

Tags: c, macros, double, expansion

Why doesn't the following work when using double (it works using int)

test.c

```
#include "myFcn.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main () {

    printf("L1: %f \n", myGet_L1());

    mySet_L1(10.0);

    printf("L1: %f \n", myGet_L1());

    return 0;
}
```

myFcn.c

```
#include "myFcn.h"

double L1 = 0.0;

double get(double *v) {
     return *v;
}

void set(double *variable, double value) {
    *variable = value;
}
```

myFcn.h

```
 #ifndef __MYFCN_H__
 #define __MYFCN_H__

 extern double L1;
 #define myGet_L1()                  get(&L1)
 #define mySet_L1(value)             set(&L1, (value))

 #endif
```

I don't see why this is working when using int but not doubles?

Comment: You need function prototypes for `get` and `set` in test.c.

Comment: Why is L1 declared as a global spaghetti variable? Any particular reason it can't be private to myFcn.c?

Comment: Get a new compiler! Implicit int function declarations were banned 18 years ago. Why would anyone use a compiler that's so old that it has not been updated during the past 18 years? (In case of gcc older than version 5.0, the issue is often mis-configuration. Use `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.)

Comment: @Lundin, it can't be private because it is used in the macro-expansion. i.e., test.c:11:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'L1',
./myFcn.h:7:42: note: expanded from macro 'myGet_L1'

Comment: @user3502042 Yeah why do you use it in the macro expansion for? That's completely superfluous and contradicts private encapsulation. `static double L1 = 0.0; ... double get(void) { return L1; }; ... void set (double value) { L1 = value; }`

Answer (score 1):

First a comment: *enable compiler warnings!* That way, you might have found the answer yourself:

Your compilation unit for `test.c` misses *prototypes* for your `get()` and `set()`, so they're implicitly assumed to be

```
int get();
int set();
```

Which means they take an unspecified number of arguments (*promoted* to `int`) and return an `int`. This happens to generate some working code if you really use `int` for your `L1`, but doesn't work with `double`.

Solution: Declare your functions in the header file:

```
 #ifndef __MYFCN_H__
 #define __MYFCN_H__

 extern double L1;
 double get(double *);
 void set(double *, double);

 #define myGet_L1()                  get(&L1)
 #define mySet_L1(value)             set(&L1, (value))

 #endif
```

---

Other notes:

- With the code you provide, there's on the other hand no reason at all to have the *variable itself* visible to other compilation units, so better *remove* the line

  ```
   extern double L1;
  ```
- identifiers starting with underscores are reserved ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10688187/2371524) for the complete rules), so the naming of your *guard macro* is not wise. Just use `MYFCN_H` instead.

Comment: `()` does not mean "unspecified number of `int` arguments", it means "unspecified number of arguments of unspecified types".

Comment: @unwind: fixed, kind of, I don't feel I should go into too much detail on this here ...

Comment: The OP might be using a dinosaur compiler that only conforms to C90. Then enabling warnings might not help them.

Comment: @Lundin sure, but is this a realistic assumption? AFAIK, even `msvc` should complain here ... well, I wrote "might" ;)

Comment: There's plenty of dinosaur compilers around. Not only Visual Studio, but various more or less exotic embedded compilers. And then SO does still get questions about completely ancient compilers like Turbo C now and then.