# What is the extra underscore( _ ) on the sal buffer annotations?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2010

I've noticed statements like:

```
  __in HMODULE Module,
  __in PSTR ImportedModuleName,
  __in PSTR ImportedProcName,
  __in PVOID AlternateProc,
  __out_opt PVOID *OldProc
```

Within these statements, I see two _ _ and then the word ( in ).

Well, while looking at sal.h I noticed under the deprecated annotations:

```
// sal.h  
_in    : The function will only read from the buffer. The
caller must provide the buffer and initialize it. Cannot be used with _deref.
```

Well there is only one underscore. I was wondering why all the source code I see on the net has two underscores( _ _ in )? Like my above statements.

Comment: The underscores mean it's a reserved identifier which is used to prevent name clashes. I don't know what the `in`/`out` stuff means though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do people use __(double underscore) so much in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224397/why-do-people-use-double-underscore-so-much-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

It is the outcome of the arms race when you have a language (C) or a compiler feature (the preprocessor) that doesn't support namespaces.  Or add non-standard keywords to the language, like `__declspec` or `__attribute__`.  Identifier names that start with an _underscore are reserved to the implementor.  Unfortunately there are more than one person that wears that hat.  The implementor can be the programmer that wrote the compiler and its CRT implementation.  Or it can be a programmer that wrote a core library, like sal.h.

Or it can be you and you decide that a header is so core to the project that you use underscores to avoid name collisions with the rest of your code.  Wrong decision, but very commonly made.

Which forces the implementor to use multiple underscores to avoid name collisions.

Answer (score 1):

`_in` you have noticed in sal.h comments is one of the possible annotation parts. The whole annotation begins from an additional underscore. See the following example:

```
NTDSAPI
void
WINAPI
DsFreeSpnArrayA(
    __in DWORD cSpn,
    __deref_in_ecount(cSpn) LPSTR *rpszSpn
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

N.B. those are not statements, they are parameter declarations.

All names that begin with double underscore or single underscore followed by uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation, meaning the compiler, standard library and OS. This ensures that if users define macros or globals called "in" it won't break the std lib because it uses __in, and users and third-party libraries must **never** define anything with such a name, so the authors of sal.h are being well behaved and not using reserved names.

The double underscore identifiers you're looking at are Microsoft's way to indicate if a parameter is only used to pass values to the function, or if it also passes data back out (i.e. a pointer or reference parameter that gets set in the function) or both. Icm surprised *all* the code you see on the net has them, you must only be looking at Windows code, maybe even only on MSDN?

Comment: "the authors of sal.h are being well behaved and not using reserved names." AFAIK, names in global scope that start with one underscore are reserved too.

Comment: Yes, the list of reserved names is more complicated than I gave in my answer. I thought the quoted comment was documenting function params, it might not be well-behaved if not.