# Why does this static funtion have three prefixes?

Tags: c, function, static, driver

I'm trying to build a driver for my SD card, but I get an error on this line:

```
static void __devexit rtsx_remove(struct pci_dev *pci)
```

Saying:

> /home/kenkron/Downloads/rts_pstor/rtsx.c:916:22: error: expected ‘=’,‘,’,‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtsx_probe’ static int __devinit rtsx_probe(struct pci_dev *pci, const struct pci_device_id *pci_id)

Why is `__devexit` before the function name, and how is it supposed to work?

Edit: my question is about what `__devexit` is in the context of the function definition.  Eugene Sh perhaps implied it was a macro, but what would it be doing in the function definition?  Other functions I've seen have, at most, static and a return type.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget a semicolon ; on the previous line?

Comment: Huh? The error is about `rtsx_probe`. The line you quoted declared `rtsx_remove`. You quoted a completely unrelated line.

Comment: @AnT The macro expansion with some undefined stuff might get the compiler confused about the actual error location

Comment: about names starting with double underscores see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224397/why-do-people-use-double-underscore-so-much-in-c)

Comment: @rahultyagi It is not a variable.

Comment: @Eugene Sh: Yes, but the information supplied in the error message itself makes it quite unambiguously clear which function this error message applies to.

Comment: @AnT Can't it be related to some syntax error *before* that function?

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: Indeed, it can be.

Answer (score 2):

`__devexit` is defined in `include/linux.h`. Make sure you include that header. If you have already done that, make sure you don't have any syntax errors in your code. Also check the previous lines for errors, like eg. a missing semicolon.