# C++ Friend Function not accessing private members

Tags: c++, arrays, object, friend

So I am trying to make a chess game ( bit of an ultimate challenge for me ), and I'm a stump for this part ..

So I made a piece object, and the idea is that in the main game code, I have an array of pieces and I pass the address of the array to the function "InitilisePieces" and the team ( Black or White ) and it shall assign all the pieces. So I made the function a friend to access all the private members and it comes up with an error saying "inaccessible", and I don't understand what's wrong with doing as I've done. Any help would be more than appreciated!

Side Note: things like State_ and _Location and structs and enums that are defined properly etc, not the problem ... ( I don't think )

Header File Contains:

```
class   __Piece
{
private:

    State_              e_state;
    Piece_Type_         e_type;
    Team_               e_team;
    _Location           st_location;

    friend void         InitilisePieces     ( __Piece(*)[16], Team_);

public:
    __Piece             ();

};
```

.cpp File Contains:

```
void                    InitilisePieces     ( __Piece * pao_piece[16], Team_ )
{
    int         n_count;

    for ( n_count = 0; n_count < 16; n_count++ )
    {
        pao_piece[ n_count ]->e_state;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Thankyou for the explanations and I get where I'm going wrong now ... so what is the parameter supposed to be to pass the address of an array of __Piece 's?

Comment: [Do not begin your identifiers with underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/a/224420/1938163)

Comment: As an aside, `__Piece` and `_Location` are reserved identifiers.

Comment: I think that getters and setters are much more suitable than friend function here

Comment: @MarcoA. Beginning with an underscore is just fine, as long as the next character is not uppercase or another underscore, and the identifier is not in global scope.

Comment: I like it, and I've never had a problem with it. and its not causing this error.

Comment: Not saying that it is the cause of your problem but it's a discouraged practice (read more from the link I posted).

Comment: @DavidHaim .. Getter Setters would be fine (ish, it would add more code ) and that was my next step, but regardless why doesn't ^^ that work

Answer (score 7):

Your friend function and the function you define later have the same name but different signatures. You have not defined the friend function.

This

```
void InitilisePieces( __Piece(*)[16], Team_);
```

is not the same as this

```
void InitilisePieces( __Piece * pao_piece[16], Team_ )
```

The former's first parameter is a pointer to an array of 16 `__Piece`s. The latter's first parameter is adjusted to `__Piece** pao_piece`, i.e a pointer to a pointer to a `__Piece`. In other words, it is this:

```
void InitilisePieces( __Piece** pao_piece, Team_ )
```

Also: watch out for [***reserved identifiers***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Great answer. It will be even better if you remove `pao_piece` from second line or add it to the first one (imho).

Comment: Ohh okay, thats fine .. but when I pass the address of the array in it says, "__Piece(*)[16] incompatible with __Piece **". How do I get around it?

Comment: @user3502489 The address-of operator applied to an array yields a pointer to an array. That isn't a pointer to a pointer. You need to figure out what you want the code to do, then implement that.

Comment: @juanchopanza I can't pass the address of "__Piece piece_array[16]" into a __Piece** though?

Comment: @user3502489 That is probably what the compiler is telling you. You can't convert pointer to array of X to pointer to pointer to X.

Comment: @juanchopanza So you cant ever pass the address of an array?

Comment: @user3502489 You can pass to something that expects the address of an array.

Comment: what would that be ...?

Comment: @user3502489 Read my answer carefully. The relevant information is in there. Otherwise ask another question (after searching for duplicates). This is unrelated to the question you posted.