# C++ create aliases for primitive types using templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, typedef

I'm trying to write some stuff to wrap simd intrinsics, and I figured that it would be nice to do something like

```
using vec<float, 4> = __m128;
```

so that I could use templates in some code I write later on. This isn't really relevant to the question, but __m128 is a type that represents 4 floats. This doesn't work, and g++ says `expected nested-name-specifier before 'vec'`. I know I can just write classes to wrap them, or I can do something like:

```
template <typename T, int N> struct vec;

template<> struct vec<float, 4>
{
    typedef __m128 type;
};
```

and then I can use `vec<float,4>::type`, but the first way is far more convenient. I think it might be possible using something like [C++ template typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef), but I'm not sure, and I wouldn't know the syntax. Is there any way to make the first statement work or to do something similar?

Comment: You may be interested in [P0214](http://wg21.link/p0214)

Comment: See answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/224397/2785528, about use of double-underscores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the first can't work. It doesn't make sense given the current rules (you can't hijack the syntax of a template like that).

Your second solution however is perfect! You just need to make a slight adjustment:

```
namespace impl {
    template <typename T, int N> struct vec;

    template<> struct vec<float, 4>
    {
        typedef __m128 type;
    };
}

template<typename T, int N>
using vec = typename impl::vec<T, N>::type;
```

Now `vec` is an actual template referring to the `type` of the corresponding struct.