# Why doesn't defining `__cxa_throw` cause a link error?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++17, libstdc++

Why doesn't the following C++ program have a link conflict with the system-provided `__cxa_throw` ?

```
#include <cstring>

void __cxa_throw(void *, void *, void (*)(void *)) {
    std::puts("bad luck");
}

int main() {
    throw 13;
}
```

Is there something magical about that symbol?  For a normal function this would be an ODR violation wouldn't it?

Comment: The runtime-provided function is probably `extern "C"`, while yours gets a mangled name. In any case, this program exhibits undefined behavior by way of using a reserved name.

Comment: ODR: _"...The compiler is __not__ required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Tried it with `extern "C"`, still works, no link error.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Sure, but for other symbols it does cause a link error - so my question is why not this one?

Comment: When linking a bunch of .obj files and static libraries together, symbols defined in .obj files take priority. That's how you can write your own `operator new`, say; but if you don't, one provided by the runtime library is used. Your program still exhibits undefined behavior; "seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: you are not allowed to define ANY symbols which starts with double underscore. Those symbols are reserved for compiler and standard library. https://stackoverflow.com/a/224420/1387438

Comment: _"but for other symbols it does cause a link error"_ No, not necessarily. Try doing that with a shared library.

Comment: *For a normal function this would be an ODR violation wouldn't it?* -- yes, but what makes you think this isn't an ODR violation? An ODR violation does not require a compiler (or a linker) diagnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Igor pointed out, you need to add `extern "C"` to prevent name mangling.

But the cause why it works is because the symbol is most likely defined as *weak*. This means that if you redefine it, the linker will use your version instead of the standard's library.

[Gcc's source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libitm/eh_cpp.cc) confirms they define it as weak. <s>I am unsure about the reason, perhaps some internal compatiblity with shared libraries and such...</s>
Actually there is a comment right above the definition I somehow missed:

```cpp
77 /* Everything from libstdc++ is weak, to avoid requiring that library
   to be linked into plain C applications using libitm.so.  */
```

So that's the reason.

It goes without saying that it is really terrible idea to do this, more even without proper documentation on what other functions expect `__cxa_throw` to do.

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder why `__cxa_throw` is defined as WEAK.  Anyone know?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I found a comment right above the function's definition, edited the answer. Somehow I missed it the first time.